# Problem with upgrade (Lubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: upgrade

I've upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS.

Now If I go to System Tools -> Software Updater I receive:

> Not all updates can be installed, run a partial upgrade to install as
>   many updates as possible.

If I click 'partial upgrade' I receive:

> can't install lubuntu-core. It was impossible to install a required
>   package

Now If I try to send a bug report the package that seems to be problematic is 'ubuntu-release-upgrader-core 1:16.04.21'.

If I run `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree        
 Reading state information... Done
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 144 not upgraded.
```

How can I resolve such problem?

**EDIT**:

If I run  `dpkg -s ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`:

```
Package: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 340
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: ubuntu-release-upgrader
Version: 1:16.04.21
Replaces: update-manager (<< 1:0.165), update-manager-core (<< 1:0.165)
Depends: python3:any (>= 3.2~), python3-distupgrade (= 1:16.04.21)
Recommends: libpam-modules (>= 1.0.1-9ubuntu3)
Breaks: software-properties (<< 0.9.27), update-manager (<< 1:0.165), update-manager-core (<< 1:0.165)
Conffiles:
 /etc/update-manager/meta-release 834e015e99673a6e3b0f31f6a511355f
 /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades df41b4619e6054b4558a75e316923611
 /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade 51540d8467fcf35f65e2873454746e54
Description: manage release upgrades
 This is the core of the Ubuntu Release Upgrader
```

**EDIT2**:

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove update-manager
sudo apt-get install update-manager
```

but the problem is still present.